# Strange URL behaviour

Tags: html, ajax, url, url-rewriting

I'm wondering how sites these days are managing their content and AJAX calls.

How is it that Facebook is able to have a URL like:
http://www.facebook.com/zuck

without with / on the end of zuck like
http://www.facebook.com/zuck/

This is obviously really handy as they don't actually need to create a sub-directory called zuck.

I noticed as well that places like http://hypem.com/popular is doing it too. Convenient for them as they're able to run their media player without breaks and they don't need to to have a # in their URL.

Comment: The answer is **.htaccess URL Rewrite**

Comment: URLs don't have to map to a filestem! `zuck/` does not have to be a directory somewhere. Some applications take the URL and map it to a filesystem, some don't (take Ruby on Rails and its `map.resources`.) And I don't understand why on Earth you came to think that the trailing slash, `#`, or absence thereof have anything to do with smooth media playback! :)

Answer (score 2):

this kind of URL mostly uses the Apache redirect rules in .htaccess files, you will see something like domain.com/example but in the back-end it is really mean redirect this to something like

domain.com/subdirectory/maybe-anotherone/example.php

so they dont want users see the exact pattern of their system.

Answer (score 2):

This is [URL rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) feature.

There might be various implementations, but basically it's done by the web server taking the request path (e.g. `/zuck/` or `/popular/songs/whatever`) and instead of looking for files in that path it parses it to parameters (there might be rules defined in HTTP stack or later on).

So `http://www.facebook.com/zuck` inside the server becomes an equivalent of `http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=zuck` (or something along those lines).

Answer (score 2):

**It's called nice-url's or URL-Rewrite.**

You can traverse all requests to the *index.php* and there you can handle it by `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP.

You need to create a file, named *.htaccess* at the root of your site. This is the code what I'm using, it keeps images, icons and some other resources out of the scope:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin/
    RewriteRule !\.(ico|gif|jp?g|png|pdf|doc?|xls?|ppt?)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```